# MySQL query error in selecting data from database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sproduct=mysql_query("select * from product_deal where deal_id=$did");

$showd=mysql_fetch_array($sproduct);

$selectcountry=mysql_query("select * from mlm_country where country_id=$showd['subcountry']");

$showcountry=mysql_fetch_array($selectcountry);
```

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE' or
>   `T_NUM_STRING'

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement.

Comment: In which Line you get the error?

Comment: in third line @ Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I changed a bit

```
$sproduct=mysql_query("select * from product_deal where deal_id='$did'");

$showd=mysql_fetch_array($sproduct);

$countryid = $showd['subcountry'];

$selectcountry=mysql_query("select * from mlm_country where country_id='$countryid'");

$showcountry=mysql_fetch_array($selectcountry);
```

Comment: nothing fetching in line 3 $countryid = $showd['subcountry'];

Comment: Anytime :). It's Elyor

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your $selectcountry line to:

```
$selectcountry=mysql_query("select * from mlm_country where country_id={'$countryid'}");
```